# Want to upload an image with Dialogflow and Google Actions

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I have a Google Action that I can share the location with and ask for some information. In order to upload an image it has to link to a web app and then upload the image there. Then that image can be seen back in Google Assistant if I then open it up again, call up the Google Action and ask for it. Is there any way of upload an image in the Google Assistant to a database? (firebase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, no. There is no API (yet) to get access to the camera on devices that have it. Your workaround is currently the most direct method we have.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I thought so. 

So I'm trying to get the most efficient UX. So they share their location and then put in the text I prompt them for. They then click the link to the web app that they then upload the image to. Can I link back to the Assistant app? 

So my question is I suppose. Can you link to Google Assistant and even better a Google Action?

Comment: That's a different question - go ahead and ask it. {: